# Stomp broker with Redis as full featured message broker

Tags: spring-websocket, spring-messaging

Is there a way to connect redis as a full featured stompbroker?

As per redis documentation, we can use redis as message broker. we are planning to use redis as a message broker for our chat product.
I am trying to connect to redis but its failing. Is there a way to connect reids message broker for stomp?

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
public class WebSocketConfig implements WebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {

  @Override
  public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
    registry.addEndpoint("/chat");
  }

  @Override
  public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry registry) {
    registry.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/app");
//    registry.enableSimpleBroker("/topic");
    registry.enableStompBrokerRelay("/topic").setRelayHost("localhost").setRelayPort(6379).setClientLogin("guest").setClientPasscode("guest");
  }
}
```

I got this exception, when I tried.
io.netty.handler.codec.DecoderException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No enum constant org.springframework.messaging.simp.stomp.StompCommand.-ERR unknown command `CONNECT`, with args beginning with:

Comment: Did you figure out this?

Comment: No. Used inmemory(simpleBroker)

Answer (score 0):

You need STOMP compatible message broker. For example [RabbitMQ with stomp plugin](https://www.rabbitmq.com/stomp.html) Spring directly pass every STOMP command to broker. There is no way to convert [STOMP command](https://stomp.github.io/stomp-specification-1.2.html#Client_Frames) to [Redis Pub/Sub](https://redis.io/topics/pubsub) command.

Comment: Not fully true...being a simple text protocol any stomp command can be sent as a redis message